# How do you learn a framework without tutorials

Tags: java, android, frameworks, libgdx, game-engine

I have been trying to learn more about Android Game Development this past month. I read the only book I could find about libGDX, and it definitely helped me get started, but there are literally no other tutorials that I have found.

My question is, how do you learn to create games using libGDX if there are no good tutorials out there? I hear a lot of people talk about documentation of libGDX and have no clue what that means.

I guess to generalize it in the most simple way possible, where do I go from here? Suppose the developer just dropped the framework on the Internet today and you were to begin trying to learn how to use it without any help. What route would you take? I'm afraid I've come to a dead end after being so excited finishing the book.

Comment: I would guess that by documentation they mean [product's `javadoc`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/). I assume that you are familiar with their [web-site](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/documentation.html#gettingstarted), it does list some tutorials.

Comment: Yes there's a few tutorials such as rendering an image, touch input, etc. But suppose I wanted to create a tower defense game, or even a simple pong game. The book I read has some collision detection but not a lot. I'm more just trying to find out how to learn this framework more instead of relying on tutorials to hold my hand.

Comment: what kind of book ? From my experience, I learned a lot from books and  it was the good start to try and develop a lot projects with java technologies by myself. But it was not about libGDX. Just wondering, that you have read a book and it was not help you..

Comment: I have no specific knowledge of this framework.  Since you stated "*I hear a lot of people talk about documentation of libGDX and have no clue what that means.*", I provided my understanding.  Have you programmed games before, possibly in a different environment?

Comment: Salvador, don't get me wrong, the book helped tremendously to get me started. It's just after that it's a dead end. Nothing else really exists in terms of different kinds of game creation. http://www.packtpub.com/learning-libgdx-game-development/book Pm,  I have done games in just java for desktop and also a few andengine books. Its a sharp learning curve and I'm trying to find the best way to go about this.

Comment: A search for `libgdx tutorials` on a major search engine turns up lots of tutorials. There is even a whole StackExchange site for game development that has a question discussing libgdx tutorials and educational resources: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/26220/where-are-all-the-tutorials-for-libgdx. Hence, I am confused when you claim that "there are literally no other tutorials that I have found" beyond one book.

Comment: Thank you for that link. I will begin to use those links to further my knowledge. But let me just ask something. Suppose all those tutorials did not exist. How does one use a framework without them? How do people learn? Is it simply just using what they know from previous coding where the framework does all of that for them already and all they have to do is call for it during their programs? I feel constrained to using tutorials for learning and feel there HAS to be a better, or at least more beneficial way of learning something than using a tutorial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a lot of documentation about libgdx:

- [Wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki)
  a game tutorial right there: [Bucket Game](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/A-simple-game)
- [Javadocs](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/)
- Another tuto: [Frogger](http://www.rengelbert.com/tutorial.php?id=175)
- [Tuto for a Game Prototype](http://obviam.net/index.php/getting-started-in-android-game-development-with-libgdx-create-a-working-prototype-in-a-day-tutorial-part-1/)
- [Tutorial Series](http://blog.gemserk.com/tag/libgdx/)
- [Another Tutorial Series](http://www.reddit.com/r/gamedev/comments/1pkgq8/libgdx_tutorial_series/)
- [Video Tutorial Series](https://www.youtube.com/user/doctoriley/videos)
- [Another Video Tutorial Series](http://www.youtube.com/user/dermetfan/videos) <- everyone talk about how good these are
- [More tuto's](https://github.com/mattdesl/lwjgl-basics/wiki#libgdx-tutorials)
- [Swap Race Game tutorial](http://theinvader360.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/street-race-swipe-libgdx-scene2d.html)
- [A ridiculous ammount of test examples](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/tree/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests)
- [Some Open Source Games](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/tree/master/demos) <-just some of the many out there
- This page in the libgdx site conveniently called ["documentation"](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/documentation.html)

**And the master of them all:** [Top Secret Site](https://www.google.com.mx/#q=libgdx+tutorial)

And I have never read that book, but I heard it's somewhat outdated (even if the release date is not far, the author started writing the book a long time ago and didn't bother to update it prior release). And if you were left clueless desperetaly trying to get your hands in a tutorial **after** reading the book:

> I'm afraid I've come to a dead end after being so excited finishing the book.

Then I will dare to say its not a good book.

Comment: The book was OK to get into the feel of developing, but didn't accomplish what I thought it would. A book more like learn java in 21 days definitely did it's job well when I was learning java exclusively. Thank you so much for all the help. I'll have my work cut out for me these next few months. I really want to specialize ingame development, and feel libGDX opens a lot of doors.

Answer (score 3):

My advice for you is:

- Take examples from your book and play with them.
- Pick a suitable example application (there were some listed on the website for example) and:

  - Start going through its source.
  - Create your own test application that follows the solutions found there.
  - Test changing different things in your app.
- Experiment with how to solve problems with new framework that you already have solved once with a framework you're familiar with. That way you know exactly what to do and just need to find what's different with the new tools.
- Find fellow developers to chat with, there surely is a mailing list, forum or IRC channel somewhere that you can discuss solutions on.
- Study the javadocs.
- If above doesn't give enough answers, study [framework source code](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx).

In my biased opinion nothing really beats hands on experience. You can read books and documentation forever, but that will only get you so far. Best way to learn how to use a framework is getting your hands dirty through trial and error. Start writing some code, any code, and tinkering with the framework. You'll slowly start to get a feeling for how things work.

Kind of like if you want to learn to speak a new language. Reading, writing, learning vocabulary and doing grammar exercises is all good and peachy, but only way to learn to speak it is by speaking, speaking and speaking.

Also, always try to engage in conversations, when you find a fellow developer. You don't want to invent the wheel anew every time you have a new issue and he could've had similar issues or know solutions to your problems. Or he could be able to offer you valuable advice where to go next.

Comment: Thank you. I guess that's exactly what I was looking for in a way. I'll take the game from the book, and try to change and manipulate it into something. Maybe try to replicate the impossible game or something since they both use levels and a side scrolling jump game play. Thank you for the help.

Comment: No problem, to use a worn phrase: "Been there, done that." Oh, and one crucial thing: *start simple*. Once you clear the basics, then you can move to something tougher, but trying to rebuild WoW as your first game is doomed to fail. :)